# MongoDB .find in many collections at once

Tags: mongodb

Can I do find in many the same collections at once?

I have several identical collections that are collected by day. I need to do a search in a few days.

Example:

collectionname_20171110
collectionname_20171111
collectionname_20171112
collectionname_20171112
etc

Is there any method?

$lookup it's not what I need, I do not "join" data from one collection with other.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. The find API works on a collection. You can try to handle on application side to throw `db.collection.find()` in parallel and merge the result.